# Errors building mysql2 gem on Mac Lion w/ rvm & ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, osx-lion, rvm, mysql2

In order to build ruby 1.9 on mac I had to install gcc 4.6.  Rails and a bunch of other gems built fine.  installing mysql or mysql2 is giving me all sorts of heartache.

> ```
> rubygems> env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql --with-mysql-lib=/usr/local/mysql/lib --with-mysql-include=/usr/local/mysql/include --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
> Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
> ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
>     ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
> ```

```
        /Users/ff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql --with-mysql-lib=/usr/local/mysql/lib --with-mysql-include=/usr/local/mysql/include --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for mysql.h... no
checking for mysql/mysql.h... no
-----
mysql.h is missing.  please check your installation of mysql and try again.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/ff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-config


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/ff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/ff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
```

When I look at the mkmf.log file I see:

> ---

```
have_header: checking for mysql.h... -------------------- no

"/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.6 -E -I/Users/ff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.2.0 -I/Users/ff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/ff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/Users/ff/.rvm/usr/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I/usr/local/mysql/include -Os -arch i386 -fno-common  -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  -fno-common -pipe  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
gcc-mp-4.6: error: i386: No such file or directory
gcc-mp-4.6: error: unrecognized option '-arch'
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <mysql.h>
/* end */
```

So basically it seems that the -arch flag is not supported.  Anyone have an idea as to where these compile options are provided so I can remove this flag?  Or any other solution.... Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install MySQL separate from when installing rails. I tried installing it with rvm and it did not work.

Check out this [article](http://www.djangoapp.com/blog/2011/07/24/installation-of-mysql-server-on-mac-os-x-lion/) it should help you with installing mysql

If that fails here's another [solution](http://web.archive.org/web/20130105011136/http://www.cowboycoded.com/2010/12/04/setting-up-rails-3-on-mac-osx-snow-leopard-10-6-4/). Both have worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. I've been running mysql for years now on my system. I'm just upgrading from ruby 1.8.x to 1.9 and having problems with the mysql2 driver.  I guess I can reinstall mysql from scratch and see if that helps.

Answer (score 15):

I tried all the solutions posted here, but was not lucky. I reinstalled mysql through homebrew a couple of times and still no luck. Then I came across a blog post with a solution.

I edited the `mysql_config` file in `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.12/bin` and removed the W-compiler options `-Wno-null-conversion` and `-Wno-unused-private-field` for `cflags` and `cxxflags`.

This solved the problem with `gem install mysql2`.

Reference: [randomactsofsentience.com/2013/05/gem-install-mysql2-missing-mysqlh-on-os](http://www.randomactsofsentience.com/2013/05/gem-install-mysql2-missing-mysqlh-on-os.html)

Comment: spent almost 2 hours on this problem till I found this solution, cheerios:)

Comment: Even though it does not answer the question for using the version at /usr/local/mysql, this worked for me since I installed MySql through homebrew.

Answer (score 3):

well, since you're living on the edge... -arch flags should be -m64 instead now... so you'll need to probably update your mysql_config to reflect that change e.g. in mine it's on line 128 replace:

```
-arch x86_64
```

with

```
-m64
```

then,

```
gem install mysql2
```

Comment: where is mysql_config located?

Comment: Thanks! This helped me when upgrading Ruby 1.8.7->1.9.3 on Snow Leopard. I didn't even have to reinstall mysql, just used:
    `env ARCHFLAGS="-m64" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config`

Answer (score -3):

Failed to build gem native extension is not about gem dependencies but its rather about the application not being installed completely.

I faced the same problem, this should do the trick:

`sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev`

Comment: that is for ubuntu. he is asking for MacOs

Comment: apt-get is not supported on osx